# apple-mobile-web-app-capable angular-ui-bootstrap modal scrolling issue

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm seeing an issue with a simple to-do list web app I am working on. I'm using

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

So it can do the iPhone standalone launch thing.

The issue I'm seeing is when the app is launched from the home screen, I scroll to the bottom of a list that goes beyond the bottom of the screen and attempt to add an item, the modal messes up as shown below:

[image: apple web app modal issue]

It's showing the items at the top of the list on top of the fixed header div and the modal itself.

The index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" manifest="app.appcache">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

    <script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/undo.css">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">

    <title>All your lists</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The view looks like this:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: left;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-top" ng-click="home()">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align: center; line-height: 40px; color: #eee">
            <h4>{{list.name}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: right">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-top" ng-click="open()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item app-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { checked: 'false' }">
        <list-item item="item" toggle="toggleItemCheck" delete="deleteItem"></list-item>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item got-item" ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { checked: 'true' }">
        <list-item item="item" toggle="toggleItemCheck" delete="deleteItem"></list-item>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css for the header div is:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #444;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

I am not seeing the issue when I look at the web app in the browser on both desktop (in mobile view) and on my iPhone - it seems to scroll to the top as the modal comes down.

Another thing I noticed with the apple-mobile-web-app-capable mode is if the modal appears while I'm at the top of a list, I can scroll down and see where the modal fade overlay ends, exposing some list items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My less than satisfactory solution to this problem was to use

```
$window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

before opening the modal